# Creating Containerized Applications on Azure with a VNet

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps

I have a set of containerized http services that I wrote, the services are configured using a `docker-compose.yml` and a collection of Dockerfiles to build the service images.  I would like to be able to host my docker-compose.yml setup on Azure, specifically one of my http services requires the ability to rotate which outbound Public IP Address it is making requests from (similar to a proxy.)

I have looked at the following resources:

- Azure App Service
- Container App
- Container Instances
- Virtual Machine

I have been able to deploy my app successfully and test it on all of the solutions, however, my issue is that one of my services needs to rotate the outbound IP Address that it is making requests from (kind of like using a proxy to make requests.)

I can accomplish this with a virtual machine and by adding a VNet with multiple IP Address resources associated.  This works perfectly fine but using the virtual machine alienates me from the benefits of azure's other managed container services.

I Have read the docs for App Service, Container App, and Container Instances and it doesn't seem like it's possible to assign these resources to a VNet with my current configuration.

Any advice on how I could go about solving my problem is appreciated.

Comment: No, this was a while ago and I believe I scrapped the docker-compose setup and decided to run with good ole dockerfiles